# Qt - splitting a QString, using several types of whitespace as separators

Tags: c++, regex, qt, split, qstring

I'm looking to split a QString. There are several words in the QString, separated by one or more(!) of the following symbols:

- whitespace
- tab
- CR
- LF

I'm looking to extract the words only. Basically, I'm trying to replicate the behavior of the Python str.split() function.

I know I can use a regular expression in order to achieve this, but what would it look like? Any other straightforward methods to achieve this are welcome as well.

Comment: So, tried `"\\s+"` yet?

Comment: I have come across this particular regexp, yes. But I am unsure if it covers all the cases.

Comment: It does seem to be enough. Try `QStringList list = str.split(QRegExp("\\s+"), QString::SkipEmptyParts);`. Else, try `\\W+` (`\W` matches non-word characters, and will split in many more cases than `\s`)

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a go and see if it is enough for the data I will be running this on.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Note that CR, LF and tab *are* already whitespace. If you need to match a whitespace you can rely on a [shorthand character class `\s`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qregexp.html):

> `\s`  Matches a whitespace character ([`QChar::isSpace()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qchar.html#isSpace)).

So, use then

```cpp
QStringList list = str.split(QRegExp("\\s+"), QString::SkipEmptyParts);
```

Or for Qt6.0:

```cpp
str.split(QRegularExpression("\\s+"), Qt::SkipEmptyParts);
```

If you plan to split a string with specific characters, use a [**character class**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

> `[...]`   Sets of characters can be represented in square brackets, similar to full regexps. Within the character class, like outside, backslash has no special meaning.

Then, try

```
QStringList list = str.split(QRegExp("[\r\n\t ]+"), QString::SkipEmptyParts);
```

You can enlarge the list later when requirements change.

Comment: On Qt6: `str.split(QRegularExpression("\\s+"), Qt::SkipEmptyParts);`